# MySQL CASE with multiple conditions in WHEN clause

Tags: php, mysql

There are tracks and albums in my database. Each track can pertain to an album. The users can update which tracks pertain to an album.

PHP receives an array of track ID's, and an album ID. I am trying to create 1 query which will update a track's album ID, and at the same time NULL a track's album ID if it doesn't pertain to the album anymore.

```
$query = "UPDATE tracks
          SET album_id =
            CASE
              WHEN album_id = :album_id AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(tempkey, :tracks) THEN NULL
              WHEN FIND_IN_SET(tempkey, :tracks) THEN :album_id
            END
          WHERE account_id = :account_id";

$statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);
$statement->execute($data);
```

The part `album_id = :album_id` doesn't seem to be working. Each time I update the album ID of any given tracks, it NULLs the album ID of all other tracks.

How could I fix this query to achieve what I want (if it's still worth it compared to just using 2 queries)?

Ps: Using `FIND_IN_SET` which is like `NOT IN / IN` but without the hassle / dirtiness which PDO poses when using that.

Comment: Seeing `FIND_IN_SET` is usually a sign you've created a schema that violates the principles of relational database design. These tend to perform really badly on non-trivial amounts of data.

Comment: Using `FIND_IN_SET` to avoid the hassle which PDO poses when using `IN`. Is `IN` is worth the hassle?

Comment: If you're fighting against PDO you might want to switch to using a full-fledged ORM so you're not on the hook for writing queries like that yourself. [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) and
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) are all good examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `ELSE` condition. Otherwise you get `ELSE NULL` by default

```
CASE
  WHEN album_id = :album_id AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(tempkey, :tracks) THEN NULL
  WHEN FIND_IN_SET(tempkey, :tracks) THEN :album_id
  ELSE album_id
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to do some filtering in the `WHERE`.  Your query attempts to update all rows for an `account_id`.  That might or might not be a good thing.

Here is one way to move some filtering to the `WHERE`:

```
UPDATE tracks
    SET album_id = (CASE WHEN FIND_IN_SET(tempkey, :tracks) > 0 THEN :album_id END)
    WHERE account_id = :account_id AND
          (album_id = :album_id OR FIND_IN_SET(tempkey, :tracks));
```

Comment: I replaced the column `album` for `album_id` to have the query work. It updates the tracks given in the :tracks input but it `NULL`s all other tracks' album ID's.

Comment: @DanP. . . . Such is the difference between `AND` and `OR`.  I fixed the logic.